# Cant update my ios app (cant upload the .ipa file to Application Loader)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios

Once i try to upload my .ipa file to application loader i get error that say:

Application Loader is unable to upload your package

my.bundle.id' is correct.

and i cannot figure out why it keeps giving me this error.

Thank you for any help.

NOTE: I used react-native to develop my app (if it changes anything...)

Comment: You could try and export manually the IPA and upload manually.

Comment: some problem in ipa file you can re export ipa and try again.

Comment: It could be a problem with your application bundle identifier , check the bundle id for your project.